# UIActivityViewController customisation: border and background color

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I would like to know if it is possible to customize the background color and border color of this component ?
I would like to replace the semi black color with white..

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on given following links . This given code will help you to better understanding.

[UIActivityViewController](https://github.com/coryalder/DMActivityInstagram)

[OWActivityViewController](https://github.com/brantyoung/OWActivityViewController)

I hope it will help you .